# How to find elasticsearch query timeout reason?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, timeout

My search query is over 400ms (using jaeger to trace), it's too slow.
I dont know why and finding reason.
Thank you.
[image]
Concurrent requests about 10

The index has 46000 records with 5 shards

Mapping

```
        "table_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer" : "standard"
        },
        "table_name_rough" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer" : "standard"
        },
```

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilderTableName = new BoolQueryBuilder();
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("is_deleted", 0));
if (Strings.isNotNullOrEmpty(keyword)) {
    boolQueryBuilderTableName.should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("table_name", keyword));
    boolQueryBuilderTableName.should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("table_name_rough", keyword));

//    table_name likes "hôm nay", "tìm kiếm",
//    table_name_rough is corresponding table_name, likes "hom nay", "tim kiem"

BoolQueryBuilderTableName.minimumShouldMatch(1);
}

if (Strings.isNotNullOrStringEmpty(userId)) {
    boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user_id", String.valueOf(userId)));
}

boolQueryBuilder.must(boolQueryBuilderTableName);

Span spanES = OpenTracerManager.getInstance().buildSpan("query ES").start();
SearchResponse searchResponse = tableElasticRepository.searchElastichByQuery(limit, page, boolQueryBuilder);
span.finish();
```

This is SearchResponse

```
public SearchResponse searchElasticByQuery(int limit, int page, BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder) throws IOException {

        sort = "_score";

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(tableIndex);
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

        searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);
        searchSourceBuilder.size(limit);
        searchSourceBuilder.from(page);
        searchSourceBuilder.sort(sort, SortOrder.DESC);
        searchSourceBuilder.minScore(0.001F);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        return searchResponse;
```

Comment: what is thread_pool search number? (according to number of processor). how much ram do you have? what is heap config? five shard in one server? why? did you try it with one shard? did you try forcemerge with one segment?

Comment: and 400 ms does not reach to elasticsearch timeout 30s.